# SAML auth in Nativescript

Tags: authentication, nativescript, saml, saml-2.0, nativescript-angular

How can I implement saml auth in nativescript app with Angular? I already have the rest api for it, but I cant find any solution or plugin for NS. I found only Kinvey but it is serverless solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on the same using [InAppBrowser](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-inappbrowser) plugin only. We have the IDP config fetched from our server and then we open the InAppBrowser for authentication.
The plugin uses Chrome Custom Tabs for Android and SafariServices/AuthenticationServices for iOS with deeplink support to the APP itself.